# BottomSheetDialogFragment theme with skins

Tags: android, android-theme, bottom-sheet, material-components, material-components-android

How to combine `BottomSheetDialogFragment` theme with other themes?

My app has skins which are made using  themes. `BottomSheetDialogFragment` should have rounded corners, and I achieve this using:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme) /* hack to make background transparent */
 }
```

Then in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>
```

But If I extend from the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog` I do not get the color scheme which I have defined in the skin theme.

So the question is: How to define Dialog theme inside the skin theme?

Comment: are you setting any view in BottomSheetDialogFragment in "setupDialog" override method?

Comment: Definitely, i inflate the XML. I do it in onCreateView actually. Finally i ended up copy pasting colors from the theme to dialog theme. Seems like the only solution :/

Answer (score 8):

You can **add** in your app theme the **`bottomSheetDialogTheme`** attribute to set globally in your app the bottomsheetDialog style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   ......
   <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialog_Rounded</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialog_Rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet_Rounded</item>
</style>
```

Otherwise in your BottomSheetDialogFragment you can override the **`getTheme()`** method.

```
public class RoundedBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

  //....

  @Override public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.BottomSheetDialog_Rounded;
  }
}
```

Also to get rounded corners you can use something like:

```
  <!-- BottomSheet Dialog-->
  <style name="BottomSheetDialog_Rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet_Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="BottomSheet_Rounded" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog_Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog_Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I know, how do you figure out all these information. Is there any documentation, or source code to refer from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

**kotlin**

```
override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme
```

**java**

```
@Override
public int getTheme() {
     return R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreateDialog(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog 
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(context!!,R.style.FullScreenBottomSheet)

<style name="FullScreenBottomSheet" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```