Limit the Maximum Expansion Height for BottomSheetDialogFragment
Currently, we have implemented the following UI components:

BottomSheetDialogFragment
NestedScrollView
EditText

The current behavior is illustrated in the screenshot below.


As the user types, the height of the BottomSheetDialogFragment increases. If the user continues to type, the height of the BottomSheetDialogFragment will expand until it fills the full screen.


However, rather than expanding to full screen, we would like the BottomSheetDialogFragment to increase in height only up to a certain point, after which it should stop to prevent it from covering the full screen. This desired behavior is shown in the following screenshot. Beyond this point, if the user continues to type, the NestedScrollView should become scrollable.


Do you have any ideas on how we can achieve this?
Below is our current implementation of the source code.
todo_input_dialog_fragment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--
    It appears that setting android:fillViewport to either true or false makes no difference
    in our case. We are following the approach used in the noteplus project.
    -->
    <!--
    Use NestedScrollView, if our bottom sheet dialog is draggable.
    -->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_regular"
            android:hint="Add a Todo"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <!--
        If we place the button in bottom sheet, we need to specific app:rippleColor explicitly, to
        prevent ripple color from using colorPrimary
    -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:translationZ="4dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:cornerRadius="28dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccentLight"

        app:rippleColor="#7fffffff"
        app:iconTint="@color/primaryTextColorDark"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/send_24px" />
</LinearLayout>

TodoInputDialogFragment.kt
class TodoInputDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private var _binding: TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var keyboardVisible = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TodoInputDialogFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val root: View = binding.root

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947700/how-to-adjust-dialog-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears-using-the-latest-windowin
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(root) { _, insets ->

            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595830/72437
            val currKeyboardVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
            if (!currKeyboardVisible && (this.keyboardVisible != currKeyboardVisible)) {
                dismiss()
            }
            this.keyboardVisible = currKeyboardVisible

            insets
        }

        binding.submitButton.setOnClickListener {
            submit()
        }

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        focusAndShowKeyboard(requireActivity(), binding.editText)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)


        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947700/how-to-adjust-dialog-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears-using-the-latest-windowin
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            dialog.window?.also {
                it.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
            }
        }

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861306/how-to-disable-bottomsheetdialogfragment-dragging
        //dialog.setOnShowListener { dialogInterface ->
        //    val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<FrameLayout>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        //
        //    if (bottomSheet != null) {
        //        val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        //        behavior.isDraggable = false
        //    }
        //}

        return dialog
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return com.yocto.wetodo.R.style.TodoInputDialogFragmentStyle
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun submit() {
    }
}

styles.xml
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58107195/72437 -->
<style name="TodoInputDialogFragmentStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet_Rounded</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>


Did  you tried providing WindowInsets , or providing max lines to EditText

why you don't use top margin?

You can achieve this by limiting the maximum lines of your Edittext. When your Edittext fills with number of line it will increase the height of the bottom shit and so the behaviour fills like the background views are invisible by the bottom shit. By changing the Edittext to below where i mentioned the maxLines attribute of the Edittext will manage the maximum height of the Edittext and so your bottom shit will never go beyond some height.
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Add a Todo"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

You can manage the lines as per your need.

BottomSheetDialogFragment uses BottomSheetDialog internally. You can change its behaviour like:
// TodoInputDialogFragment.kt

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).getBehavior().setMaxHeight(400) // <-- add this
    return dialog
}


This approach wouldn't work and it causes unwanted side effects. By using TodoInputDialogFragmentStyle, the bottom sheet dialog is made to appear above the keyboard. If you apply setMaxHeight, it will disrupt this behavior.

@CheokYanCheng can you share TodoInputDialogFragmentStyle code?

Sorry. I have updated.

Yes, you can limit the maximum height of bottomSheet at run time. Here is the medium article about it
https://dorianpavetic.medium.com/android-sticky-view-at-the-bottom-of-bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-ac91242bc1b7
You can also review its sample on github
https://github.com/dorianpavetic/StickyBottomSheet?source=post_page-----ac91242bc1b7--------------------------------

Probably you would add layout change listener to register changes to the EditText, and limit the height if exceeded a certain value:
binding.editText.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, left, top, right, bottom, oldLeft, oldTop, oldRight, oldBottom ->
    val dialogHeight = requireView().height
    val maxHeight = 700 // rough value
    if (dialogHeight > maxHeight) {
        requireView().setLayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, maxHeight)
        )
    }
}

or use binding.editText.addTextChangedListener instead.
